# Unable to install a nuget package using powershell in bamboo

Tags: powershell, nuget, bamboo

I am trying to install a nuget package from below powershell script.

```
$buildUtilsVersion = "0.1.1-feature-hfp-xxxxxxxx"
$buildUtilsPackageName = "scripts.deploy"
Invoke-Expression -Command ".\src\Nuget.exe install $buildUtilsPackageName -version $buildUtilsVersion -OutputDirectory .\deploy\application\content\lib -configFile .\src\Nuget.config"
```

If I run through PowerShell locally, it works fine. But the same fails in bamboo with below error

> ResourceUnavailable: Program 'nuget.exe' failed to run: No such file or directory At line:1 char:1
> .\src\nuget.exe install scripts.deploy -version 0.1.1-f …

Could you please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the path you specified is valid for Bamboo agent which runs the command. Pay extra attention to **Working subdirectory** field of your script task.